# Material2 - Datepicker custom validator value does return date object rather than string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material2

Im creating a custom validator for `datepicker` using reactive form group.

in my **.ts** file

```
form: FormGroup;

constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private validatorSrv: CustomValidatorService,
) {}

createForm(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({ 
        trans_date: [null, [Validators.required, this.validatorSrv.validDate]] 
    });
}
```

Now in my class `CustomValidatorService`

```
validDate(c: AbstractControl): any {
   // It always return 'Mon Jan 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)' 
   // When value is 1
   // And 'Sat Dec 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)'
   // When value is 12
   console.log(c.value); 
}
```

In the above example it always return js datetime object.

**How can i get the actual input value from the custom validator AbstractControl?**

Answer (score 0):

This is a common behavior. What you can do is convert the date to string in your validator.

In case you don't know, the datepicker from Angular Material can actually use moment.js.

In your case, maybe you could use it ? This would resolve your issue, you would just have to convert your date with one of the many functions available in moment.

Comment: What i want is the actual input of a user in a date picker or the actual value of the control itself.  So whether to parse/convert the object to any string still it wont change the long datetime format of that object in string.

Comment: Well if your validation is a valid date, simply test if you have an actual date. If not, then it means your user haven't provided a valid date. I'm not sure you can get the input text value in a validator. I know you can in the component though.

Comment: The reason why i need it done with string it because i have a logic that validate the user date input if the format is mm/dd/yyyy or mm-dd-yyyy using regular expression otherwise it returns an `invalidDate:true`

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is the most simple or recommended approach for having a custom date validation. Since it is a common behavior to have a date object instead of a stringed user input. Using an AbstractControl custom format validation makes thing more complicated to me.

So i just wrote a simple function on `keypress` event of the control and try to validate that way.

```
isValidDate(): boolean {
   // A lengthy logic was omitted here for simplicity sake...
   if (format is mm/dd/yyyy or mm-dd-yyyy) { return true; }
   return false;
}


onTransDateKeydown(e: any): void {
    const c = this.form.get('trans_date');

    if (this.isValidDate(e.target.value)) {
      c.setErrors(null);
    } else {
      c.setErrors({ invalidDate: true });
    }
}
```

You can give an error to a ReactiveForm Control using `setErrors()` method programmatically and that is awesome.